# Notes Document as an objects in array

Tags: c#, lotus-domino

Chaingin my question.

I have my C# application open a nodes data base. So right now I can open my notes data base and grab the properity value that I want.  Now there is only 4 values I need for each note.

What is the best way of storeing these items value together so I can reference them when i want?  ArrayList?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with Lotus Notes document format but if you cannot store the documents themselves in an array and just access the properties that way, you could create a class that stores the properties for a document and then create a `List<t>` that holds the list of class instances you created.